# input type="range" - sending data from view to controller in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a problem with sending data from view to controller by a slider.
Data can be send as a object or a variable, but it still doesn't work.
Can someone help me?

This is slider in view:

```
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>
                    <p>@Model.UserDeterminants[0].DeterminantName.Value</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Examine" asp-action="SubmitValue" asp-route-range="range1" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" value="points" method="post" class="rd-form">
                        <input type="range" defaultValue="0" name="range1" id="my_range1" min="-100" max="100" onload="updateSliderValue(this.value)" onchange="updateSliderValue(this.value)"/>
<p><span>0</span></p>
<button class="button button-block button-primary button-pipaluk" type="submit">Zatwierdź</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>@Model.UserDeterminants[1].DeterminantName.Value</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

```
    <script>
        $('#my_range1').on("change mousemove", function () {
            $(this).next().html($(this).val());
        });
    </script>
```

And a controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SubmitValue (int range)
        {
...
        }
```

Comment: You are submitting the value so the it should be [HttpPost] instead of [HttpGet]. Also your Action Parameter in the controller should be: public IActionResult SubmitValue ([FromBody] TableName range)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thank you @noobprogrammer.
I changed [FromBody] to [FromForm].
Working solution in view:

```
<form asp-action="Submit" asp-route-range="range" asp-route-Id="@Model.Id" method="post">
  <input type="range" defaultValue="0" name="range" id="range1" min="-100" max="100" onload="updateSliderValue(this.value)" onchange="updateSliderValue(this.value)" />                        <p><span>0</span></p>
  <button class="button button-block button-primary button-pipaluk" type="submit">Zatwierdź</button>
</form>
```

```
<script>
        $('#my_range1').on("change mousemove", function () {
            $(this).next().html($(this).val());
        });
    </script>
```

and in controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Submit ([FromForm] int range, int Id)
        {
...
        }
```